# Ошибка при соединение с SQL SERVER

Tags: c#, sql-server

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При подключении к бд выдает ошибку

Comment: Вы уже убедились, что имя экземпляра указано правильно, и что на SQL Server разрешены удаленные соединения? Ну и, до кучи, что он вообще запущен?

Comment: @Yaant я всё перепробовал

Comment: Покажите строку соединения, которую используете в своей программе.

Comment: Откройте в Студии Sql Server Object Explorer и в свойствах СУБД можете посмотреть реальную строку соединения.

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 2):

Понимаете, когда Вы приводите текст ошибки, и при этом не приводите текст программы, в которой возникла ошибка - то это во первых, нарушает правила задавания вопросов ("должен быть фрагмент прогарммы, описывающий проблему в воспроизводимой форме" - как то так), а во вторых, просто не даёт возможности даже тем людям, которые хотят вам помочь, сделать это.

Теперь о самой ошибке.

У вас программа не соединяется с SQL сервером.

Причин может  быть несколько:

1. нет SQL сервера. Ведь это - отдельная программа, которая должна быть установлена и запущена
2. нет доступа по сети в SQL. Даже если он установлен у Вас на машине - у него может быть закрыт приём внешних коннектов
3. непарвильные логи - пароль - имя сервера.
4. неправильный протокол
5. Неправильная строка коннекта. Приведу пример правильной: `const string sqlConnectionString="Password=qwertyuiop123;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=MyFirstDatabase;Data Source=192.168.1.25";`

Теперь у Вас есть вводная информация, чтобы конкретизировать вопрос.

Comment: И порт может отличаться от дефолтного 1433

Comment: да, причем в строке коннекта это отражается указанием порта через запятую, по моему. В общем, как то нестандартно. Никогда запомнить не мог, всегда гуглил